# Html code is not showing in woocommerce shop page on adding in header.php?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have added some code in header.php but it is not showing in shop page. It is showing all other pages.

```
      if( is_home() || ! $ed_section  || ! ( is_front_page()  || is_page_template( 'template-home.php' ) ) ){
    echo '<div class = "container"><div id="content" class="site-content">
<div class="tab1">
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/appetizers-snacks/">Appetizers & Snacks</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/fillers-international/">Fillers International</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/meals-more/">Meals and More</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-indian/">Mains Indian</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-oriental/">Mains Oriental</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-international/">Mains International</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/desserts-drinks/">Desserts And Drinks</a>
 </div>
    <div class = "row">';
} ?>
```

This is my code and I added the lines `<div class="tab1">
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/appetizers-snacks/">Appetizers & Snacks</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/fillers-international/">Fillers International</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/meals-more/">Meals and More</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-indian/">Mains Indian</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-oriental/">Mains Oriental</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-international/">Mains International</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/desserts-drinks/">Desserts And Drinks</a>
 </div>`

This tab class is showing in all pages excepts shop page, category page, product page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use WooCommerce conditional tags instead of the default? For example, if you want this block of content to appear for all pages, use `is_woocommerce()` or if it should only appear on the main shop page, use `is_shop()`.

For example:

```
if( is_woocommerce() ){
    //echo your content here...
} ?>
```

Source: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: THANKU FOR YOUR ANSWER.

Comment: No problem! Be sure to post back and confirm it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if( is_home() || ! $ed_section  || ! ( is_front_page()  || is_page_template( 'template-home.php' ) ) ){
    echo '<div class = "container"><div id="content" class="site-content">
<div class="tab1">
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/appetizers-snacks/">Appetizers & Snacks</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/fillers-international/">Fillers International</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/meals-more/">Meals and More</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-indian/">Mains Indian</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-oriental/">Mains Oriental</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/mains-international/">Mains International</a>
<a class="cat_button" href="https://packnchew.com/product-category/desserts-drinks/">Desserts And Drinks</a>
 </div>
    <div class = "row">';
} ?>
```

Check out very first line,

*if( is_home() || ! $ed_section  || ! ( is_front_page()  || is_page_template( 'template-home.php' ) ) ){*

The code inside that block is for Home Front page only.
If you want that to work on all pages, I will recommend you to put above that or include woocommerce in the if statement as well.

Good Luck.